# How to set up Time Machine to back up to a specific folder in my Synology NAS?

Tags: finder, network, backup, time-machine, nas

I'm trying to set up Time Machine to back up to my Synology NAS. I need it to back up to this folder:
`/Shared/BACKUPs/MacBookPro2010`

So on my Mac I go to Finder -> Go -> Connect to server

and specify:

`afp://192.168.1.105/Shared/BACKUPs/MacBookPro2010`

I then provide user and password and it connects.

But when I go to time machine and click "Select Backup Disk" it shows "Shared" and if I select it, it starts dumping backup files into the root `Shared` folder on the NAS.

How do I coax it to put the backup into `/Shared/BACKUPs/MacBookPro2010` instead?

Comment: Did you enable the TIme Machine functionality on the NAS? I found this much easier to use, you just point TM to your NAS then and TM itself makes sure that each Mac gets its own directory (sparse bundle).

Comment: @nohillside no, I didn't. How do I do it?

Comment: https://nascompares.com/guide-to-synology-nas-with-time-machine/, https://majorgear.tech/guides/how-to-set-up-time-machine-on-synology/

Answer (score 3):

Time Machine requires a drive or shared volume. Time Machine will not work with a nested folder. On your Synology, set up the destination directory as a shared volume to your Mac.

See Synology's [How do I back up files from my Mac to Synology NAS using Time Machine?](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Backup/How_to_back_up_files_from_Mac_to_Synology_NAS_with_Time_Machine)

> This article will guide you through the process of backing up data from your Mac to Synology NAS using Apple's Time Machine, a backup utility included with macOS 10.5 and later.